# Netsuite - Create Custom Item Field with Formula

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create a custom item field in netsuite that calculates (field1*field2*field3)/1728. I tried to put this in the formula field under the default value but nothing is calculating: ({custitem_field1} *{custitem_field2} * {custitem_field3})/1728. I've also verified that the field type is the same as the three fields i'm trying to reference. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things in this situation:

1. You probably want to make the field non-stored. (on the custom field configuration page). This value will not be available in saved searches.
2. Make sure formatting is off for the constituent fields. This shouldn't make a difference but it has (at least in the past)
3. Unless all your fields always have values you need to decide what the value will be when any of them are empty.

e.g. if a blanks should calculate as a 0

```
(nvl({custitem_field1},0) * nvl({custitem_field2}, 0) * nvl({custitem_field3}, 0))/1728
```